# Error with scikit learn CV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

When I try in Python the following

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
```

but then when I try to define the KFold

```
kf=KFold(33,10, shuffle=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-f6318606322e> in <module>()
----> 1 kf=KFold(33,10, shuffle=True)

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'shuffle'
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: what does 33,10 signify ? how may folds i.e. train/test iteration where test size being (1/k) you want the model to run ?

Comment: 33 and 10 are the train/test split. That way is how it was defined in the video. :(

Comment: oh okay.It takes only one value i.e.n_splits

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax for defining kfold -

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
```

where n_splits define the number of folds(splits) you want the dataset to be .So for a value of n_splits =3 implies that you will have 3 iterations dataset run on the modelwith split into train,test(test=1/k)

Comment: if this has worked for you,could you pls accept it as right answer